# Sheeana and the prophecy of the new sandrider?

Tags: dune, heretics-of-dune

In the book *Heretics of Dune*, the Bene Gesserit and the Priesthood both believe that Sheeana confirms a prophecy from Leto II that a new sandrider would appear.

Can someone point me to the specific reference in *God Emperor of Dune*?  Is it in the Sister Chenoeh dialog, or in Siona's test, or the Stolen Journals?

Comment: Scanning thru my electronic copies of all the books, I don't see sandrider used (other than the above reference) after the first trilogy.  It's possible different phrasing was used, but, given the length of his reign, the idea that he may have left many prophecies 'off-camera' is not that unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't recall it specifically being mentioned in *God Emperor of Dune*, the last chapter mentions where the Bene Gesserit would have learned of it—from Leto's journals themselves, linking his thoughts recorded by the Ixian printers in a No-place discovered at Dar-es-Balat.

Answer (score 1):

There's a brief reference in *Heretics of Dune* to the prophecy (but not the specific wording).

> Lucilla concealed her alertness. Giant worms. Not Shai-hulud. Not
>   Shaitan. Giant worms. **The sandrider predicted by the Tyrant had
>   appeared at last!**

Comment: Yes, i know this reference, i'm wondering what it points to in God Emperor of Dune